# How to dynamically get each element's innerHTML when accessing by class

Tags: jquery

How to dynamically get each element's innerHTML when accessing by class?

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/DwDsL/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use [.each](http://jqapi.com/#p=each)

```
$('.btnItem').each(function(){
 // do your stuff using $(this)
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

use [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function with [class](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) selector and [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function to get innerhtml

```
$('.classname').each(function() {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: Only if stackoverflow would have show a log of edits, that would eliminate any misunderstandings like this.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `.wrap`:

```
$(".btnItem").wrap('<div></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.btnItem').wrap('<div/>');
```

is enough

if you want to replace `<span>` with `<div>` remaining its html then try

```
$('.btnItem').replaceWith(function(a, html) {
   return '<div>' + html + '</div>';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("span.btnItem").each(function(index) {
    $("<div>" + $(this).html() + "</div>").insertAfter($(this));
    $(this).remove();
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fz9bn/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function g() {  
    $(".btnItem").each(function(){
       con = $(this).text();
       $("<div>" + con + "</div>").insertAfter(".btnItem")
    })

    $(".btnItem").remove();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DwDsL/1/